What is quantum microscopy by coincidence (QMC) and how important is it?
This is a soft question on the prospects of quantum microscopy by coincidence (QMC)$^\dagger$. I may be starting undergrad research on quantum imaging using QMC techniques. However, I am not able to find much information on this particular field except for a few references:

Bennink, R. S.; Bentley, S. J.; Boyd, R. W. (2004). Quantum and classical coincidence imaging. (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.033601)
Scarcelli, Giuliano; Yun, Seok H. Entangled-photon coincidence fluorescence imaging. (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.16.016189)

How is the field in terms of future potential, and how much progress is currently being done on imaging using QMC?
Edit: My current understanding is that this is a method developed to image microscopic biological systems. It uses bi-photons (a pair of entangled photons) to double the momentum associated with a certain wavelength, thus allowing double the usual resolution without having to increase the light frequency to keep the system from being damaged.
$^\dagger$ No, this is not Quantum Monte Carlo...

If it is the idea to increase the resolution using quantum methods then there is quite a large literature on the topic.
